# Scope of a Static Variable in Seam

Tags: seam, scope

If I define a static variable in a class having Page Scope, then what will be the Scope of the Static Variable? Will it persist the data even if I navigate away from that page and then come back to that page(here by page I mean the xhtml page on which I am referring to the static variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static fields are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Seam Scopes don't change the meaning of static.  The page context allows you to associate state with a particular `instance`, but if you assign a value to a static field that value will be share by all instances regardless of your Seam Scope.

> Will it persist the data even if I navigate away from that page and
>   then come back to that page(here by page I mean the xhtml page on
>   which I am referring to the static variable)?

Yes, since you have one classloader for your web application, the scope of your static variable should be more than page scope.

Comment: Are you certain that the scope of the static variable will be Application scope? I tested it, and the scope was more than page scope but less than Application Scope.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet Logan but You are right maybe the scope is less than Application Scope. It's  depends on the SEAM's classloader implementation and when your class it's unloaded